# How can I unset an active class on each child component while setting it to active for the clicked child

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to set an active class on child component B while disabling the active class on child component A when I click on B.

So far I have tried using hooks in the parent class where I unset the active prop on all childs by using `setActive('');` followed by setting the class of the current target to link--active by using `e.currentTarget.className === 'link--active' ? e.currentTarget.className = '' : e.currentTarget.className = 'link--active';`. Sadly all it does at this moment is add the class or remove the class on the clicked child.

Parent:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');

  const navigate = (e) => {
    setActive('');
    e.currentTarget.className === 'link--active' ? e.currentTarget.className = '' : e.currentTarget.className = 'link--active';
  };
```

and in the return statement:

```
{menuItems.map((item, index) => (
  <li key={index} >
    <NavLink target={item} onClick={(e) => navigate(e)} active={active} />
  </li>
))}
```

Children:

```
<a href="#"
   onClick={props.onClick} 
   className={props.active}>
   {props.target}
</a>
```

Edit:

After using the solution from Ori Drori, the active class was set on the clicked NavLink and removed from the rest. Since I wanted the onClick to be the navigate function, all I changed was set the onClick in the parent to navigate and have the navigate function call setActive by using id as param and calling setActive in the navigate function with id as a param again. The classes now look like this:

Parent:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

const navigate = (id) => {
  setActive(id);
};

return (
    {menuItems.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id} >
        <NavLink 
          {...item}
          isActive={active === item.id}
          onClick={navigate} />
      </li>
    ))}
)
```

Child:

```
const NavLink = ({id, target, isActive, onClick}) => {
  return (
      <a href="#"
        onClick={useCallback(() => onClick(id), [id, onClick])} 
        className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        {target}
      </a>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `setActive` to the NavLinks. When a `NavLink` is clicked it sets it's `id` via `setActive`. Each item also receives the `isActive` property, which is `true` if the `active` state matches it's `id`.

```js
const { useCallback, useState } = React

const NavLink = ({ id, target, isActive, onClick }) => (
  <a href="#"
     onClick={useCallback(() => onClick(id), [id])} 
     className={`navLink ${isActive ? 'active' : ''}` }>
     {target}
  </a>
)

const Parent = ({ menuItems }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null);

  return (
    <ul>
      {menuItems.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id} >
          <NavLink 
            {...item} 
            onClick={setActive} 
            isActive={active === item.id} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const items = [{ id: 0, target: 'Ready' }, { id: 1, target: 'Player' }, { id: 2, target: 'One' }]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent menuItems={items} />,
  demo
)
```

```css
.navLink {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, currently it does work, however the next problem I am running into is the fact that each navlink now calls setActive instead of navigate in which setActive is also called. Is it possible to call navigate which in turn will call setActive?

Comment: Never mind, I have found the solution, I will post it in the edit

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have a state entry in the parent like `whichIsActive`, and give it a set property of the active link with the onclick function, like the index for example.

```
const navigate = (index) => {
this.setState{(whichIsActive: index)}
 };
```

Then in your className you can do something like `className=${this.state.whichIsActive === index && 'active'}` (without forgetting the ` around). I have not tested it, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) `Assign an id to each of child components` 
(2)`Add inactive class to all child components`
(3) `Remove inactive class from selected component and add active class to it`. 
 This is the working solution for your question. I hope it helps.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    childComponents: [
      { id: "ironman", component: <IronMan /> },
      { id: "captainamerica", component: <CaptainAmerica /> },
      { id: "thor", component: <Thor /> },
      { id: "loki", component: <Loki /> },
      { id: "spiderman", component: <Spiderman /> }
    ],
    currComponentId: ""
  };

  clickHandler = idComponent => {
    // get access to all classes
    if (this.state.currComponentId !== "")
      document
        .getElementById(this.state.currComponentId)
        .classList.remove("active");
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName("child-components");
    for (let index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
      element[index].classList.add("inactive");
    }
    document.getElementById(idComponent).classList.remove("inactive");
    document.getElementById(idComponent).classList.add("active");
    this.setState({ currComponentId: idComponent });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent">
        <ul>
          {this.state.childComponents.map(element => {
            return (
              <li>
                <button
                  id={element.id}
                  className="child-components"
                  onClick={() => this.clickHandler(element.id)}
                >
                  {element.id}
                </button>
                {this.state.currComponentId === element.id ? (
                  <span> Active component</span>
                ) : null}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <div>
          {this.state.childComponents.map(element => {
            if (element.id === this.state.currComponentId)
              return <div>{element.component}</div>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const IronMan = () => <div>This is IronMan Component</div>;
const CaptainAmerica = () => <div>This is CaptainAmerica Component</div>;
const Thor = () => <div>This is Thor Component</div>;
const Loki = () => <div>This is Loki Component</div>;
const Spiderman = () => <div>This is Spiderman Component</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.active {
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.inactive {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.parent{
 border: solid 1px #322f31;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```